# React Native (Expo) Send an Email with created PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, nodemailer

I need some help on how to send an Email with a created PDF via Expo and Nodemailer.

I have my Backend Function for the NodeMailer setup and tested to actually work.

In the Frontend I have tried few different Expo Packages but always had something that would not work for me.

How I want it to work is:

1. On Button Press open the created PDF
2. When the user wants he can close the File
3. In the Background send that opened File via my NodeMailer

What I've tried:

```
 await Print.printAsync({
   html,
   orientation: "portrait",
   printerUrl: this.state.selectedPrinter?.url, 
 })
```

This creates my File and I can save it as PDF! Now this would actually work for me if I could automatically rename the File. When I press save as PDF it is called "Document" but I need to have it named dynamically. I guess if I could rename it I might be able to pick it somehow and send it (like Expo DocumentPicker or FileSystem maybe).

Second approach is to save the File and then open it:

```
const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({ html });
console.log('File has been saved to:', uri);

try {

  const cUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri);
             
  await ExpoIntent.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
      data: cUri,
      flags: 1,
      type: "application/pdf",
  });
}catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

The Code saves my File and opens it up again. Now here is a URI I can access which looks kinda like this:

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540xyyxwyx%252FPXXXX/Print/eb03cc8c-9c29-4d08-aed8-f10eXXX87fe5.pdf
```

When I try to use that URI and send it via nodemailer it tells me that the file does not exist!

```
Error Mail: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Dev\Programmierung\rn\xxx-Server\file:\data\user\0\host.exp.exponent\cache\ExperienceData\%2540xxyx%252Fxxx\Print\cbcff690-d608-4138-a635-93cxxy72a2ed.pdf'
```

Which makes sense since that file is not available on my PC, its only inside my Emulator. How do I tell Expo the correct URI Link?

So whats important (one of the two):

1. Renaming the File and save it under the correct name
2. using the correct URI

I also had some approaches renaming the File using Expo Filesystem and Expo Sharing but not really the way I wanted it. If anyone could give some advice on how to achieve this would be great, or even different approaches with Expo DocumentPicker for example.